# Calling a second variable argument macro from a variable argument macro in C++ with (Windows WPP tracing)

Tags: c++, macros

I'm working with WPP (Windows Tracing) and the basic macro looks like this:

`trace(SEVERITY, SOURCE, "%s started", app_name);`

I would like to do is something like this but I get a variety of compiler/trace errors:

```
#define trace_with_console(__level, __flags, __format, ...)  \
    do                                                       \
    {                                                        \
        printf(__format, __VA_ARGS__);                       \
        trace(__level, __flags, __format, ...);              \
    } while (false);
```

Is there a correct way to call the trace macro from the trace_with_console macro?

EDIT: Thank you everyone for replying. The problem isn't a macro issue, it is the WPP for Windows trace processor failing.

This tool parses the trace macro call and extracts the text to keep it secret, and replaces it with a GUID. You need debugging information to read the traces.

The processor gets confused by the trace macro being called within this context. At this stage it doesn't seem possible to do what I'm trying to do. @jxh answer works well, just not with WPP.

Thank you all again!

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: "*I get a variety of compiler/trace errors*". Please show the exact code as a [mre] as well as the exact errors.

Comment: What `trace` macro are you referring to? The code in the question shows a `trace` function, not a macro. Do you mean that? Or some other macro that your function is conflicting with?

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is nothing in the post that particularly screams C++ to me? (Ok, other than the title.)

Comment: @jxh: The title suffices. But OP can pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the `trace()` macro or function other than how you are trying to invoke it, I would rewrite your proposed macro as:

```
#define trace_with_console(__level, __flags, __format, ...)  \
    do                                                       \
    {                                                        \
        printf(__format, __VA_ARGS__);                       \
        trace(__level, __flags, __format, __VA_ARGS__);      \
    } while (false)
```

1. Replace the `...` in the call to `trace` with `__VA_ARGS__` instead. The contents of the variable arguments represented by `...` in your arg list for `trace_with_console` will be used in the expansion of `__VA_ARGS__`.
2. Remove the `;` at the last line of your macro. This allows your macro to be treated as a statement that requires a `;` at the end.

One disadvantage with the macro as it is written is that there are arguments that will be evaluated twice. Once evaluation will happen in the call to `printf`, and another evaluation in the call to `trace`.

Since `__format` and `__VA_ARGS__` are being passed into `printf`, we assume `trace` can accept the same format specifications and corresponding arguments. Then, if there is a reasonable max size for your trace message, you may avoid multiple argument evaluation by using `snprintf`.

```
#define trace_with_console(__level, __flags, __format, ...)  \
    do                                                       \
    {                                                        \
        char __buf_for_trace[BUF_FOR_TRACE_MAX_SIZE];        \
        snprintf(__buf_for_trace, sizeof(__buf_for_trace),   \
                 __format, __VA_ARGS__);                     \
        printf("%s", __buf_for_trace);                       \
        trace(__level, __flags, "%s", __buf_for_trace);      \
    } while (false)
```

In C++, you can remove the macro and use a variadic template function instead.

```
template <typename LevelType, typename FlagsType, typename... Types>
void trace_with_console (
        LevelType level, FlagsType flags,
        const char *format, Type... args) {
    printf(format, args...);
    trace(level, flags, format, args...);
}
```